# Why do we use &error in Swift?

Tags: ios, pointers, swift

I commonly see a pointer to an optional error variable being used, just like in this block of code:

```
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)
{
    var error: NSError?

    if !fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: &error)
    {
        println("Error removing the file : \(error)")
    }
}
```

Why do we do this?

Comment: Read the section about "Error Reporting" in [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

Comment: Have a look at the pointers section http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/c-basics.html and a bit more complex one http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/pointers-in-objective-c/225700236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error parameter is an `inout` parameter, and can set the value of `error` rather than returning it from the function. Look up "inout" in Apple's iBook on Swift.